# Rational number between any rationals, *irrational* doubt of rational numbers

Tags: set-theory, rational-numbers

This might be very odd question but hope be still worthy...

$\mathbb{Q}$ is known as countable, as it is a union of countable sets $\mathbb Q_n, n\in \mathbb N$, where
$$ \mathbb Q_n = \left\{{a\over b}: a, b\in \mathbb Z, b\ne 0, a+b=n \right\} $$

Hence we can enumerate rational numbers as a sequence $\left\{q_n\right\}\vert_{n\in \mathbb N} $ by giving them an index in an total order(order of ascending in magnitude). Here is the problem looking for. Think of two consecutive rational numbers $q_i$ and $q_{i+1}$ for some $i$. Then, there must be no other rationals between them, but I can make one, for instance, the average $(q_i+q_{i+1})/2$. So, re-index it(ackward process I would say, but just for curious), like infinitely many times to overcome this contradictory things, until the moment that there is no other rationals between them. Is it possible though? The assertion I've made should not make a postulation that $\mathbb Q$ is not a countable set. Then how can I explain that it's still possible to give an index to each rational numbers?

What is wrong with my logic? There should be a fatal error, but couldn't find it. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Two rationals with no other rational between them?  Impossible.  As you re-index to avoid one problem, you will introduce more problems, a never-ending process.  You never reach "that moment" you desire.

Comment: This is not clear.  Yes, it is not possible to find two distinct rationals without another rational between them.  No, that does not contradict the countability of the rationals.

Comment: "Think of two consecutive rational numbers $q_i$ and $q_i+1$ for some $i$. Then, there must be no other rationals between them" -- No, "next" does not mean "next in magnitude".

Comment: "*by giving them an index in an order*" $\;-\;$ But *not* in the natural order.

Comment: Basically your error is of the sort that $\Bbb N$ should not be countable, because between every integer $n$ and infinity there is always a natural number in-between. Or said otherwise, always a bigger $m$ than $n$. But here you can see yourself, why this is not valid.

Comment: @r.e.s. What if I gave an order in an increase of magnitude?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is there a reason why we can make a situation in N, comparing n and infinity rather than two consecutive natural numbers i and i+1?

Comment: You can't put the rationals in increasing order. If 0 is the first one, what is the second one?

Comment: "Then, there must be no other rationals between them" There is no such requirement. Bijections do not need to preserve the order type of the domain, not even in the finite case.